# Site or page not found error while doing http post from android

Tags: android, eclipse, xampp

link to php script from Android

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.101/learning/index.php");
```

I am getting the follwing error in the logcat as an HttpResponse. I am using a broadband internet connection and xampp as my local server. What may be the problem ?

```
04-23 14:33:45.747: D/response(19050): <html><head><title>Document Error: Site or Page Not           Found</title></head>
04-23 14:33:45.747: D/response(19050):      <body><h2>Access Error: Site or Page Not Found</h2>
04-23 14:33:45.747: D/response(19050):      <p>Cannot open URL</p></body></html>
```

In index.php i have got the code to handle post data.

Comment: where is your server? on your local machine and are you trying to acces it from the emulator?

Comment: My server is on my local machine and i am trying to access from a mobile device.

Comment: are you able to call it from the devices browser with that url?

Comment: and are you really sure that your machine/server has this ip `192.168.0.1` usually this is your routers ip

Comment: sorry i was mistake . Actually it is HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.101/learning/index.php"); I will edit it.

Comment: are you able to call it from the devices browser with that url?